# What is faster/better: Loop over each row of a dataframe or split it into a list of length `nrow` , R

Tags: r, dataframe, parallel-processing, future

I am just wondering if this is a serious tradeoff one should consider.
Let's say you have a dataframe in R and want to perform an operation on each observation (row).
I know it is already a delicate issue to iterate over the rows, so I was just wondering which of the three option:

- Normal for loop over each row
- Split dataframe into a list of `nrow` elements and apply operation on each element and bind the result together
- Do the same as above in parallel

Without any benchmarking or so, this is basically what I am asking in pseudocode:

```
library(future.apply)

n = 1000000
x = 1:n
y = x + rnorm(n, mean=50, sd=50)

df = data.frame(
  x = x,
  y = y
)

# 1)
# iterating over each row with normal for loop
for(r in 1:nrow(df)){
  row = df[r, ]
  r = f(row)
  df[r, ] = row
}

# 2)
# create a list of length nrow(df) and apply do something to each list element
# and rowbind it together
res = df %>% split(., .$x) %>% lapply(., function(x){
  r = f(x)
})

bind_rows(res, .id="x")  

# 3)
# create a list of length nrow(df) and apply do something to each list element in parallel
# and rowbind it together

res = df %>% split(., .$x) %>% future_lapply(., function(x){
  r = f(x)
})
bind_rows(res, .id="x")
```

Probably none of the above options is the best, so I'd be happy to head any thoughts on this. Sorry if this a very naive question. I am just getting started with R.

Comment: `split` is almost certainly the wrong approach. Based on your desire to do one row at a time in a `future`, consider `future.apply::future_Map` on the columns you need to pass to your `f(.)`.

Comment: You don't need to use `split()`, just loop over the indices. Or if you have a function that actually takes the values from the columns, you can use `furrr::future_pmap_dfr()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very often use the scheme `tibble %>% nest %>% mutate(map) %>% unnest`.
Take a look at the example below.

```
library(tidyverse)
n = 10000

f = function(data) sqrt(data$x^2+data$y^2+data$z^2)
tibble(
  x = 1:n,
  y = x + rnorm(n, mean=50, sd=50),
  z = x + y + rnorm(n, mean=50, sd=50)
) %>% nest(data = c(x:z)) %>% 
  mutate(l = map(data, f)) %>% 
  unnest(c(data, l))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 10,000 x 4
       x     y     z     l
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  67.1 136.  151. 
 2     2  75.4 127.  148. 
 3     3 -11.1  38.9  40.6
 4     4  58.1 106.  121. 
 5     5  23.5 126.  128. 
 6     6  73.4 179.  193. 
 7     7  44.5 121.  129. 
 8     8 106.  131.  169. 
 9     9  32.5 140.  144. 
10    10 -27.7  82.7  87.8
# ... with 9,990 more rows
```

For me personally, it is very clear and elegant. But you can disagree with that.

**Update 1**

Honestly, your question also intrigued me in terms of performance. So I decided to check it out.
Here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)

n = 1000
df = tibble(
  x = 1:n,
  y = x + rnorm(n, mean=50, sd=50),
  z = x + y + rnorm(n, mean=50, sd=50)
)

f = function(data) sqrt(data$x^2+data$y^2+data$z^2)

f1 = function(df){
  df %>% nest(data = c(x:z)) %>% 
    mutate(l = map(data, f)) %>% 
    unnest(c(data, l))
}
f1(df)

f2 = function(df){
  df = df %>% mutate(l=NA)
  for(r in 1:nrow(df)){
    row = df[r, ]
    df$l[r] = f(row)
  }
  df
}
f2(df)


f3 = function(df){
  res = df %>% 
    split(., .$x) %>% 
    lapply(., f)
  df %>% bind_cols(l = unlist(res))
}
f3(df)


ggplot2::autoplot(microbenchmark(f1(df), f2(df), f3(df), times=100))
```

Here is the result:
[image]
Do I have to add anything else and explain why the scheme `tibble%>% nest%>% mutate (map)%>% unnest` is so cool?

Comment: Thanks a lot:) That looks really nice, I just need some time to go through this and see how I can apply this to my problem. But why is this so much faster?

Comment: Why this solution is faster? I don't know for sure, but it seems to be related to the internal optimization of the `dplyr` package. But I know that almost always the `for` loop in R is a bad idea. And the truth is, I find fewer and fewer reasons to use it.
On the other hand, the scheme `tibble%>% nest%>% mutate (map)%>% unnest` is very clear to me. Here, I could link to many examples on this site where I showed others how to apply it. However, it is better to consult a real guru. I suggest you read Chapter 25 *R for Data Science* https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html carefully

Comment: thank you very very much!:) Highly appreciated

Comment: In the case of a stack overflow, appreciation is expressed when you accept the answer.