# How to improve the efficiency of my slow code

Tags: r, performance, coding-efficiency

I am running a huge simulation that requires intensive calculations at least given my low-level coding skills. I believe the slow calculations are due to the `for` loop. I tried to vectorize everything in order to make the code efficient. However, the code is *not* working. The following example is just for clarification.

```
## Data Generation:
#----------------------------------------------------------
n = 500
p = 7

X <- cbind(1, MASS::mvrnorm(n, rep(0,p), 0.5**(abs(outer(1:p, 1:p, "-")))))
z <- runif(n)

B <- c(3, 2, -1.5, rep(0,(p-2)))

y <- X %*% B + rnorm(n)
#----------------------------------------------------------

## Differencing based on z and creating weights
#----------------------------------------------------------
U <- outer(c(z), c(z), "-")

W       <- U
diag(W) <- 0
W       <- W %*% diag(1 / colSums(W))

a <- matrix(NA, n, (p+1))
for(j in 1:n){

   X1    =  X * U[,j]
   a[j,] = solve(t(X1) %*% diag(W[,j]) %*% X1, t(X1) %*% diag(W[,j]) %*% y)

}
```

In order to get rid of this `for` loop, I had to do the following:

```
ones <- matrix(1, nrow = n, ncol = 1)

Y      <- ones %x% y
Big_X1 <- (ones %x% X) * c(U)
Big_W  <- c(W)
```

I am not sure if

```
solve(t(Big_X1) %*% diag(Big_W) %*% Big_X1, t(Big_X1) %*% diag(Big_W) %*% Y)
```

would be the right way to obtain the same results as above. When I try it, I get an error message

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 46.6 Gb

Is it possible to compute the above calculations (i.e. in the `loop` calculations) with the vectorized variables? If so, how? if not, are there other ways to make my code efficient?

Comment: Please check your code, you seem to be missing a number of `)` characters.

Comment: Look here. Perhaps you will find something for yourself here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69118504/what-is-faster-better-loop-over-each-row-of-a-dataframe-or-split-it-into-a-list/69123590#69123590

Comment: I bet you could cut the time in half by using the RcppEigen package for the %*% and solve operations, but keep the loop.  I don't know how much extra performance you are looking for.