# How to refer to data frames dynamically in an R for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

R novice, so apologies in advance. I want to write a for loop that does sequential operations on a series of dataframes and then binds them (by sequence number).
Ideally, I'd think it would be something like this (where sc2 is the base dataframe I'm working from, week3 is the selection variable used. The dataframes I'm trying to create would be t1, t2, t3,... and w1, w2, w3,... etc. In other words, the 'i' in the dataframe name would read from the for statement.

```
  for(i in 1:16) {
  ti= tail((subset(sc2, sc2$week3<i)),  n=200)
  wi= subset(sc2, sc2$week3==i)
  mi=rbind(ti, wi)
}
```

Which I'm sure you know doesn't work. I've gotten this far -

```
  for(i in 1:16) {
  txi= tail((subset(sc2, sc2$week3<i)),  n=200)
  assign(paste0("trst",i), txi,  envir = .GlobalEnv)
  wxi= subset(sc2, sc2$week3==i)
  assign(paste0("w",i), wxi,  envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Which creates a dummy dataframes (*xi) that are then assigned for each i to the global environment. But now how to rbind them? Is there a more elegant way to do all of this, or am I missing something about the way to refer to the dataframes dynamically?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it in a loop!
This can be done much easier by holding `data frame` in `data frame` or rather I should write `tibble` in `tibble`. See the example below.

```
library(tidyverse)

sc2 = tibble(
  week3 = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE),
  x = rnorm(100)
)

ftxi = function(i) sc2 %>% filter(week3<i)
fwxi = function(i) sc2 %>% filter(week3==i)

df = tibble(id = 1:16) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(txi = map(id, ~ftxi(.x)),
         wxi = map(id, ~fwxi(.x)))
```

Let's see what is `df`.

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   id [16]
      id txi               wxi             
   <int> <list>            <list>          
 1     1 <tibble [0 x 2]>  <tibble [4 x 2]>
 2     2 <tibble [4 x 2]>  <tibble [6 x 2]>
 3     3 <tibble [10 x 2]> <tibble [6 x 2]>
 4     4 <tibble [16 x 2]> <tibble [6 x 2]>
 5     5 <tibble [22 x 2]> <tibble [4 x 2]>
 6     6 <tibble [26 x 2]> <tibble [4 x 2]>
 7     7 <tibble [30 x 2]> <tibble [6 x 2]>
 8     8 <tibble [36 x 2]> <tibble [4 x 2]>
 9     9 <tibble [40 x 2]> <tibble [3 x 2]>
10    10 <tibble [43 x 2]> <tibble [6 x 2]>
11    11 <tibble [49 x 2]> <tibble [3 x 2]>
12    12 <tibble [52 x 2]> <tibble [4 x 2]>
13    13 <tibble [56 x 2]> <tibble [6 x 2]>
14    14 <tibble [62 x 2]> <tibble [5 x 2]>
15    15 <tibble [67 x 2]> <tibble [5 x 2]>
16    16 <tibble [72 x 2]> <tibble [7 x 2]>
```

As you can see it is a `tibble` which has other `tibble` in it.
So let's see if everything is correct and take a look at the second row.
First, let's look at the txi variable `df$txi[[2]]`

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  week3       x
  <int>   <dbl>
1     1 -0.0829
2     1 -2.15  
3     1 -0.949 
4     1 -0.0583
```

Now it's the turn of the variable wxi `df$wxi[[2]]`

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  week3       x
  <int>   <dbl>
1     2 -0.0643
2     2 -0.228 
3     2 -0.620 
4     2 -1.21  
5     2  0.186 
6     2  1.19
```

Bingo you get what you expected!
It is also a very quick method. You can see my other answer in this forum
[What is faster/better: Loop over each row..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69118504/what-is-faster-better-loop-over-each-row-of-a-dataframe-or-split-it-into-a-list/69123590#69123590)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Like I said, a novice, but this looks like a cool solution. I get the tibble w/tibbles in each cell as above. I'm still working on how to bind (append) them, and then do operations on them (maybe in a function?), but this is a start!

Comment: I'm glad that I helped. Remember that on Stack Overflow you say thank you by selecting the approved solution.