# Applying a vegan function across all combinations of variables present in data frame in R

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to run a Bray Curtis dissimilarity between observations by volunteers and professional biologists. I have a data set "tidy" that I am working on, and a results data set "BCresult.ex" that I would like to add the results to. For each unique existing combination of "Workbook", "Location" and "Method" I would like to compare the "Vol" row of observations to the "Bio" row of observations. Each unique existing combination of Workbook/Location/Method corresponds to a sample taken at a site.

I have used "filter" to successfully subset one Workbook/Location/Method combination and compare the observations between the "Vol" and "Bio" rows, and then append the result to the last column of "BCresult.ex". I would like to figure out how to apply this function to all of the combinations present in "tidy".

"tidy"

```
# A tibble: 24 × 7
   Workbook Location   Method Observer  Worm Larvae Swimmer
   <chr>    <chr>      <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 A        BigCreek   K      Vol          4      4       1
 2 A        BigCreek   K      Bio          4      4       1
 3 A        BigCreek   L      Vol          2      3       2
 4 A        BigCreek   L      Bio          5      2       3
 5 A        BigCreek   V      Vol          5      2       3
 6 A        BigCreek   V      Bio          3      3       3
 7 A        SmallCreek K      Vol          1      1       2
 8 A        SmallCreek K      Bio          2      4       2
 9 A        SmallCreek L      Vol          2      4       3
10 A        SmallCreek L      Bio          4      2       4
# … with 14 more rows
```

BCresult.ex

```
   Workbook   Location Method Score Bray
1         A   BigCreek      K     2   NA
2         A   BigCreek      L     3   NA
3         A   BigCreek      V     1   NA
4         A SmallCreek      K     3   NA
5         A SmallCreek      L     1   NA
6         A SmallCreek      V     2   NA
7         B   BigCreek      K     1   NA
8         B   BigCreek      L     1   NA
9         B   BigCreek      V     1   NA
10        B SmallCreek      K     1   NA
11        B SmallCreek      L     3   NA
12        B SmallCreek      V     3   NA
```

I can run this:

```
Observation <- filter(tidy, Workbook == "A" & 
                         Location == "BigCreek" &
                         Method == "K")

BrayC = vegdist(Observation[,5:7], "bray") 
BrayC 

BCresult.ex %>%
  mutate(Bray = BrayC)
```

To produce this:

```
   Workbook   Location Method Score Bray
1         A   BigCreek      K     2    0
2         A   BigCreek      L     3    0
3         A   BigCreek      V     1    0
4         A SmallCreek      K     3    0
5         A SmallCreek      L     1    0
6         A SmallCreek      V     2    0
7         B   BigCreek      K     1    0
8         B   BigCreek      L     1    0
9         B   BigCreek      V     1    0
10        B SmallCreek      K     1    0
11        B SmallCreek      L     3    0
12        B SmallCreek      V     3    0
```

and ideally, once I figure out how to loop, I get this:
I am unsure how to set up the loop. Do I make lists of all variables and loop through that? Or make a list of all existing combinations and use that? The real data set doesn't have every possible combination. Do I simply point to a location (every two rows) and do it that way?

```
   Workbook   Location Method Score       Bray
1         A   BigCreek      K     2 0.00000000
2         A   BigCreek      L     3 0.29411760
3         A   BigCreek      V     1 0.15789470
4         A SmallCreek      K     3 0.33333330
5         A SmallCreek      L     1 0.26315790
6         A SmallCreek      V     2 0.30000000
7         B   BigCreek      K     1 0.30000000
8         B   BigCreek      L     1 0.18181820
9         B   BigCreek      V     1 0.14285710
10        B SmallCreek      K     1 0.44444440
11        B SmallCreek      L     3 0.08333333
12        B SmallCreek      V     3 0.17647060
```

Oh wow, you made it to the end! I hope that is clear, new question asker here and clearly newish R user. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vegan)

tidy = read.table(
  header = TRUE,text="
Workbook Location   Method Observer  Worm Larvae Swimmer
 A        BigCreek   K      Vol          4      4       1
 A        BigCreek   K      Bio          4      4       1
 A        BigCreek   L      Vol          2      3       2
 A        BigCreek   L      Bio          5      2       3
 A        BigCreek   V      Vol          5      2       3
 A        BigCreek   V      Bio          3      3       3
 A        SmallCreek K      Vol          1      1       2
 A        SmallCreek K      Bio          2      4       2
 A        SmallCreek L      Vol          2      4       3
 A        SmallCreek L      Bio          4      2       4
 B        BigCreek   K      Vol          4      4       1
 B        BigCreek   K      Bio          4      4       1
 B        BigCreek   L      Vol          2      3       2
 B        BigCreek   L      Bio          5      2       3
 B        BigCreek   V      Vol          5      2       3
 B        BigCreek   V      Bio          3      3       3
 B        SmallCreek K      Vol          1      1       2
 B        SmallCreek K      Bio          2      4       2
 B        SmallCreek L      Vol          2      4       3
 B        SmallCreek L      Bio          4      2       4  
  ") %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(
    Workbook = Workbook %>% fct_inorder(),
    Location = Location %>% fct_inorder(),
    Method = Method  %>% fct_inorder(),
    Observer = Observer %>% fct_inorder()
  )

BResult.ex = read.table(
  header = TRUE,text="
  Workbook   Location Method Score Bray
         A   BigCreek      K     2   NA
         A   BigCreek      L     3   NA
         A   BigCreek      V     1   NA
         A SmallCreek      K     3   NA
         A SmallCreek      L     1   NA
         A SmallCreek      V     2   NA
         B   BigCreek      K     1   NA
         B   BigCreek      L     1   NA
         B   BigCreek      V     1   NA
         B SmallCreek      K     1   NA
         B SmallCreek      L     3   NA
         B SmallCreek      V     3   NA
  ") %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(
    Workbook = Workbook %>% fct_inorder(),
    Location = Location %>% fct_inorder(),
    Method = Method  %>% fct_inorder()
  )

fVeg = function(data){
  xveg = data %>% select(Worm:Swimmer)
  if(any(is.na(xveg$Worm), is.na(xveg$Larvae), is.na(xveg$Swimmer))) {
    data %>% mutate(Bray = rep(NA, nrow(xveg)))
  } else {
    data %>% mutate(Bray = rep(vegdist(xveg, "bray"), nrow(xveg)))
  }
} 
  

  
BResult.ex %>% left_join(
  tidy, by = c("Workbook", "Location", "Method")
) %>% group_by(Workbook, Location, Method) %>% 
  group_modify(~fVeg(.x))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 22 x 9
# Groups:   Workbook, Location, Method [12]
   Workbook Location   Method Score  Bray Observer  Worm Larvae Swimmer
   <fct>    <fct>      <fct>  <int> <dbl> <fct>    <int>  <int>   <int>
 1 A        BigCreek   K          2 0     Vol          4      4       1
 2 A        BigCreek   K          2 0     Bio          4      4       1
 3 A        BigCreek   L          3 0.294 Vol          2      3       2
 4 A        BigCreek   L          3 0.294 Bio          5      2       3
 5 A        BigCreek   V          1 0.158 Vol          5      2       3
 6 A        BigCreek   V          1 0.158 Bio          3      3       3
 7 A        SmallCreek K          3 0.333 Vol          1      1       2
 8 A        SmallCreek K          3 0.333 Bio          2      4       2
 9 A        SmallCreek L          1 0.263 Vol          2      4       3
10 A        SmallCreek L          1 0.263 Bio          4      2       4
# ... with 12 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! When I try this I get this error:  Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function". Where might that be coming from?

Comment: Remove objects from the workspace then run all my code. It works for me without errors.

Comment: OK, success this time! Thank you! Any thoughts on how I might change this if my real data set has 43 "species" instead of 3? Could you select by column number instead?

Comment: I'm glad that I helped. Remember that on Stack Overflow you say thank you by selecting the approved solution. The solution should work without problems with any number of workobook, locations and methods. This is because the computation is performed on the grouped data `group_by (Workbook, Location, Method) %>% group_modify(~fVeg(.x))`.

Answer (score 0):

My advisor and I ended up using this for loop as that is what he is more familiar with. It produced exactly what I was after for this application and on my real data set.

```
for(i in 1:length(BCresult.ex$Workbook))
{
  
  workbook.temp.ex <- BCresult.ex[i, "Workbook"]
  location.temp.ex <- BCresult.ex[i, "Location"]
  method.temp.ex <- BCresult.ex[i, "Method"]
  
  BCdata.temp.ex <- tidy[tidy$Workbook == workbook.temp.ex &
                          tidy$Location == location.temp.ex &
                          tidy$Method == method.temp.ex,
                        5:7]
  
  BCresult.ex[i, "Bray"]  <- vegdist(BCdata.temp.ex,'bray')
  # test  <- as.numeric(vegdist(BCdata.temp,'bray'))
  
}
```

Result:

```
> BCresult.ex
   Workbook   Location Method Score               Bray
1         A   BigCreek      K     2                  0
2         A   BigCreek      L     3  0.294117647058824
3         A   BigCreek      V     1  0.157894736842105
4         A SmallCreek      K     3  0.333333333333333
5         A SmallCreek      L     1  0.263157894736842
6         A SmallCreek      V     2                0.3
7         B   BigCreek      K     1                0.3
8         B   BigCreek      L     1  0.181818181818182
9         B   BigCreek      V     1  0.142857142857143
10        B SmallCreek      K     1  0.444444444444444
11        B SmallCreek      L     3 0.0833333333333333
12        B SmallCreek      V     3  0.176470588235294
```

The only issue: Something about the "bray" function in vegan returns the Bray-Curtis values as characters, not numeric. We just exported as a .csv and then reloaded that .csv into R to work around that. Using as.numeric didn't seem to work.

Comment: If I'm allowed to make suggestions, I don't recommend using a `for` loop in R. You may look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69118504/what-is-faster-better-loop-over-each-row-of-a-dataframe-or-split-it-into-a-list/69123590#69123590) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69364736/for-nested-loops-performing-slow-with-list-of-tibbles-in-r/69368167#69368167) at my answer.

Comment: `vegan::vegdist()` *never* returns characters but it only returns numeric data. Something you did in your code changes returned numbers to characters.

Comment: @JariOksanen I believe we traced the issue to filling column Bray with the word "test" in quotes as a test prior to running the for loop. This seemed like it made the column a chr column. Removing that step (not pictured here) solved the issue.

Comment: @HamiltonV: yes, that casts number to character.

Comment: @MarekFiołka I appreciate the suggestion! I have been reading about the other methods, and I hope to become proficient in doing things that way. For this example, it made sense to stick with a for loop so that my advisor and I were on the same page as that is what he is more familiar with. I appreciate your help!